# Uncaught ReferenceError: typeorm_1 is not defined at window.onload

Tags: javascript, nestjs

[image]I was working on my NestJS app when this error started happening when I try to visit Swagger in browser and I don't know why. The app used to work just fine. I tried cloning repo again, restarting and cleaning Docker but nothing helped

Comment: try to clean cache in the browser and rebuild your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was caused by giving `ApiProperty` decorator an `example` of plain TypeORM entity. Actually should wrap inside Type.

Bad:

```js
@ApiProperty({ description: "My endpoint desciption", example: SomeEntity })
```

Good:

```js
@ApiProperty({ description: "My endpoint desciption", example: Type(() => SomeEntity) })
```